# Could I use a 5-S BMS with only 3 cells?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, bms

I am analyzing an open-source BMS [project](https://github.com/ceech/BQ76920-BMS) based on a BQ76920 from Texas Instruments and checking its [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq76920.pdf?ts=1678426793611&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FBQ76920) to understand their features and applications.
The schematic of the project seems to be consistent with the datasheet but my question is:
Could I use it for only 3 cells in series instead of 5? what should I do for only using 3 cells instead of 5 cells?

Reading the datasheet I think I should pull down the VC5 and VC4 to VSS (GND) with a 10 kΩ resistor according to the text highlighted in yellow:

[image]

Do you think that is correct? or is there something I am not considering?
Thank you!

Comment: The note (1) you've highlighted in yellow only applies to the TS1 pin. You'll notice on the end of the description for that pin there's a (1) in superscript and not on any of the other pins.

Comment: That is correct! So do you think is it possible to use only 3 cells instead of 5? The datasheet also says: Up to 5 cells so I guess it should be possible to use only 2 o 3 for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the highlighed note applies to the `(1)` in the description next to the Thermistor description. It does not apply to all pins.

According to the datasheet device comparison, your device does support use with 3 to 5 cells, so it should be possible to use it with just the three.

[image: Device Comparison]

Later in the datasheet it describes how to connect fewer cells than specified. This is documented in section 9.1.8 on page 39:

[image: Connections for fewer cells]

So for 3 cells, you short the pins VC4, VC3 and VC2 together, and connect them to the node in the battery pack between cells 2 and 3.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It is really clear now